# Chrome's network tab preview isn't showing what's in response

Tags: google-chrome

This seems to have started happening last week, in chrome's dev console, under the network tab and under the response subtab for any http request I can see the response from the server in json format in a single line:
[image]

And under the preview tab it used to format whatever is in the response tab to look pretty, but now I'm getting this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone experiencing the same issue, it looks like it was a bug with Chrome. I updated Chrome to the latest version (Currently `66.0.3359.181`) and it got fixed.